# Executable file made using Pyinstaller doesn't start

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I want to convert the following sample python program into an executable file:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

To convert it into an executable I have used `Pyinstaller`:

```
pyinstaller app.py --onefile
```

And the EXE file is getting generated in the `dist` folder, but when I run it, it launches and immediately closes, and the expected print statement is not even displayed.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does prints the statement, but just after printing it the code ends. You can add `input()` or use `time.sleep(seconds)` to make your program wait until you press a key or any particular number of seconds respectivly.

To check if your code(without the advice i have given) prints, start that python file in your command line.